# measuring the distance from a point to another in meshlab for slam kinect data

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect.toolbox, slam-algorithm

I'm going to use openslam to reconstruct my room.
The reconstructed data will be save in PLY or PCD format and 
view by meshlab.

meshlab has a measuring tool for measuring the distance from
one point to another.

My question is will the measuring tool give me the exact distance
in unit for example cm or meter ?

Answer (score 0):

Meshlab will give you the exact distance in units of the mesh. Therefore you have to make sure, that the SLAM-Algorithm you use produces a pointcloud in correct scale. As far as I know data from kinect is assigned the depth in millimeter. If your SLAM doesn't scale the pointcloud you should be able to measure that.